# Using sql to add to dates during a query

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have a table that keeps track of when particular events occur, and how long they last. For reasons I cannot fathom, it was designed to store the start date of the event, start time of the event, then the number of hours and minutes the event lasted.  Like this:

EventStartDate | EventStartTime  |  TimeSpentHours  | TimeSpentMinutes

Where EventStartDate is a dateTime with the hours/minutes always set to zero, so that, even though it's a date time, all the values are like "12/22/2016 00:00".  The EventStartTime is a char(4) which is military time of the start of the event.  TimeSpentHours is and int which is the total hours the event duration, and TimeSpentMinutes is an int for the number of minutes.  Obviously the total time spent for the event is the hours plus the minutes.

The problem:  I need to be able to, given a particular DateTime, find all the events that were occuring during that time.  Put another way, given a particular DateTime I need to get all the events with a starting date and time that's greater than or equal to the given DateTime and less than or equal to an "end" date and time.

So I need to compute the "EndDateTime" based off the values in the database during the query.  The database is SqlServer 2008 R2.   I am using C# for WinForm application to query the data.

So far I have roughly:

```
public static List<ImportantEvents> GetEventsDuringDateTime(DateTime timeOfEvent)
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlConn = getAndOpenSqlConn())
            {
                string theEventTime = timeOfEvent.ToString("hhmm");
                string sqlStmt = "SELECT EVENT_ID,  AGENCY, EVENTSTARTDATE, ACTNOTE, EVENTSTARTTIME, TIMESPENTHOURS, TIMESPENTMINUTES  FROM EVENTSMAIN WHERE((EVENTSTARTDATE<= @MYEVENTDATETIME AND EVENTSTART TIME< @ACTTIME) AND ...";"
            }
        }
```

(the above SQL obviously won't work and is where I am stuck...)

My question is:  how can I, *in the query*, add the EVENTSTARTTIME to the EVENTSTARTDATE to create a new "temporary" column, then add the TIMESPENTHOURS and TIMESPENTMINUTES to that column into another new "temporary" column, to then query against given a specific DateTime value???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to achieve this in a single query with a common-table expression like this:

```
With StartAndEndTimes As (
    Select Event_ID,

        EventStart = DateAdd(Minute, Convert(int, Right(EventStartTime, 2)), DateAdd(Hour, Convert(int, Left(EventStartTime, 2)), EventStartDate)),
        EventEnd = DateAdd(Minute, Convert(int, Right(EventStartTime, 2))+TimeSpentMinutes, DateAdd(Hour, Convert(int, Left(EventStartTime, 2))+TimeSpentHours, EventStartDate)) 
      From EventsMain)
Select Event_Id, EventStart, EventEnd, <<add other fields here>>
  From StartAndEndTimes
  Where EventStart <= @MyEventDateTime
    And EventEnd > @MyEventDateTime;
```

Basically you can extract the hours and minutes from the start time and add them to the start date to get a true, `datetime`, start date. Similar with the end date. It is not necessary to use common-table expression here, but it does make the code more readable. Then you just do the ordinary date comparison to your input parameter.

Comment: Genius.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here I have disected parts of the final query. You will need to put the final part into your query wherever you need it.

```
SELECT Combined = EVENTSTARTDATE + EVENTSTARTTIMEFROM FROM EventsMain

SELECT CombinedWithHour = DATEADD(hh, TIMESPENTHOURS, Combined) FROM EventsMain

SELECT CombinedWithMinute = DATEADD(mi, TIMESPENTMINUTES, CombinedWithHour) FROM EventsMain
```

All together:

```
SELECT DATEADD(mi, TIMESPENTMINUTES,  DATEADD(hh, TIMESPENTHOURS, EVENTSTARTDATE + EVENTSTARTTIME)) FROM EventsMain
```